# Retrieving a previous version of a google cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to retrieve a previous version of a Google Cloud Function?

I am aware that this question has been asked before, but the answers are not working.
What I have tried is searching for a `bucket` containing my older version, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A workaround to retrieve an older version of Cloud Function would be to download it from the [GCS bucket](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying#deployment) named as `gcf-sources-${projectId}-${regionId}`. Clicking on the provided url (see below) would let you download copies of the files used for each Cloud Function deployment.[image]

Comment: It worked!! You have to look for Buckets (Storage) and after identifying the version, you can download it.